# error with AsyncTask - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading

I am getting error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.
My app is working fine on emulator. Then I check it on some devices, It is working fine with android version 2.3.5 but giving error with second device which has version 4.0.3.
I am using AsyncTask as follows :

```
private class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "",
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        userid = new PropertyInfo();
        userid.setName("UserId");
        userid.setValue(UserId);
        userid.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(userid);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = true;
        envp.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envp.getResponse();
            Response = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (dialog != null) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        try {
            splitData = result.split("\\;");
            username.setText(splitData[0]);

            URL newurl = new URL("" + WebsiteURL + "/images/profileImg/"
                    + splitData[1] + "");
            Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl
                    .openConnection().getInputStream());
            userphoto.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            username.setText(e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        URL newurl = new URL("" + WebsiteURL + "/images/profileImg/"
              + splitData[1] + "");
        Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl
                  .openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

in `onPostExecute()` is supposed to be in `doInBackground()`

and in `onPostExecute()`

```
if(mIcon_val != null){
   userphoto.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
}
```

Comment: I have solved it. we can't change UI in doINBackground() so there is no mean of it. If I do it then my app will crash in all version devices.

Comment: @JeetenParmar you can use onPostExecute(result) for setting the iamge in imageview

Comment: @JeetenParmar I didnt mean you change your UI in `doInBackground()`. Do the `decodeStream()` in `doInBackground()`. And obviously change the UI in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

You are running network related operation on the main ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html.

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

**This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher**. **Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged**.

```
     Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl
                .openConnection().getInputStream());
```

onPostExecute(param) is invoked on the UI thread. So move the above to doInBackground().doInbackground invoked on the background thread. Remember not to update ui in doinBackground(). The result of doInbackground computation is a parameter to onPostExecute(result). So you can update ui in onPostExecute(result).

Please check the topic under the section The 4 steps in the below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

You're calling this piece of code:

`Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl
                    .openConnection().getInputStream());`

in your onPostExecute. This means the code gets executed on the main thread again, causing your `NetworkOnMainThread exception`. Save the image into a variable in the `doInBackground`, and set the image to the `ImageView`in the `onPostCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

These codes inside `onPostExecute(String result)`

```
        Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl
                .openConnection().getInputStream());
        userphoto.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
```

are executed **in the main thread**, move the code into `doInBackground`, or try creating one more AsyncTask for the above Code, and run the new AsyncTask on the first Asynctask's `onPostExecute(String result)` ^^

Answer (score 0):

Google added NetworkOnMainThreadException in Android 3.0 I believe so to force developers to comply with the best practice of not running network operations on the UI thread because it freezes the App, that's why its working fine on 2.X and not on 4.X.

Move all network operation into doInBackground then only set the image in onPostExecute as the others have suggested.